# Azure DevOps - Access control over state of the work items

Tags: azure-devops

please does anyone know if it is possible to restrict who can change state of the work item on a state by state basis?

E.g. that only limited people can move item to Done, another group can mark item as removed, etc.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to use custom rules in your process. Check the following links:

- [Add a rule to a work item type (Inheritance process)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/custom-rules?view=azure-devops)
- [Restrict state transitions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/settings/work/rule-samples?view=azure-devops&tabs=inheritance#restrict-state-transitions)